# CSS placement: Horizontal and vertical placement of a text and a button

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a CSS placement problem.

For a project I use clipboard.js to copy the content of a p tag.

In a div, I have my text on the left and a button on the right with an icon to copy the text. The size of the text is dynamic and I cut the text if it exceeds the length of the div.

I'm looking for a :
1 - Align the text vertically (on several lines if the text is too long)
2 - Put the button on the right with a margin on the left.
3 - center the button vertically

I managed to put the text and the button on one line with the `display: inline-block` property but both the button and the text are not vertically centered.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/n70jrymp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is what you looking for, i changed the display: inline-block for flex and centered the content.

```css
#container {
    width: 80% !important;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
#result{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.resultItem {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    line-height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.resultItem>p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    margin: 0;
}

.resultItem>.clippy {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url("https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v1/72x72/1f4cb.png");
    /* Twitter clipboard emoji */
    background-size: 60% auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.clippy:before {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 35px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
}

.clippy:after {
    content: 'Copy to Clipboard';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 40px;
    left: -37px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.clippy:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.clippy:hover:before,
.clippy:hover:after {
    display: block;
}

.clippy:active,
.clippy:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.clippy:active:after,
.clippy:focus:after {
    content: 'Copied!';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mustard-ui@latest/dist/css/mustard-ui.min.css">
<div id="container">
    <div id="result">
        <div class="resultItem" id="test">
            <p>My wonderful strzfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddstrzfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddstrzfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddstrzfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddstrzfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddstrzfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
            <button class="clippy" data-clipboard-target="#test"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, i was typing when u answered so i just deleted mine. Also, yours a little better than mine, i messed up few things.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much for your help !!